# Display total questions of Moodle in Wordpress

Tags: embed

I have a site with Moodle and Wordpress and I'm looking for how can I display the total number of questions in Wordpress.

For example if I have 3 different courses for sale with Woocomerce, I would like to display in their descriptions "The course A have 2321 questions", "The course B have 5582 questions", etc.

Anyone know come code or similar? I haven't found anything on Internet.

Thanks!

Comment: Moodle appears to have [a bunch of APIs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Core_APIs) that you might be able to use, but I don't know which one would provide the number of questions for a course. This is a question better suited to the Moodle support community.